# toggleClass multiple classes with one click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a faq where the answer toggles on click but and it also toggles a class of a div to change a color. It works fine for the first div but I would like to trigger another class as well with the same code, I almost got it to work by adding another toggleClass but .c also toggles .b instead of to .d

```js
$(".faq div.answer"), $(".faq div.faqbox").click(function(a) {
  a.preventDefault();
  var n = $(this).parent().find("div.answer");
  $(".faq div.answer").not(n), n.slideToggle(), $(this).find("div").toggleClass("a b").toggleClass("c d")
});
```

```css
.answer {
  display:none;
}

.a { width:20px; height:20px; background:#000000; }
.c { width:20px; height:20px; background:#888888; }
.b { width:20px; height:20px; background:#ff0000; }
.d { width:20px; height:20px; background:#00ff00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="faq">

  <div class="faqbox">
  <span>Question <div class="a"></div></span>
  </div>

  <div class="answer">
  Answer
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="faq">

  <div class="faqbox">
  <span>Question <div class="c"></div></span>
  </div>

  <div class="answer">
  Answer
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Does someone has a solution where class .a would toggle to .b and if the div has class .c it would toggle to .d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle class will remove a class if it exists and add it if it doesn't, this means that the `$(this).find("div").toggleClass("a b").toggleClass("c d")` statement will always add the three classes that the element doesn't have.

To fix this, you could get all child elements that have the class `a` or `b` and toggle the `a b` classes and do the same for the `c d` classes, here is an example:

```js
$(".faq div.answer"), $(".faq div.faqbox").click(function(a) {
  a.preventDefault();
  var n = $(this).parent().find("div.answer");
  n.slideToggle(); 
  $(this).find("div.a, div.b").toggleClass("a b");
  $(this).find('div.c, div.d').toggleClass("c d");
});
```

```css
.answer {
  display:none;
}

.a { width:20px; height:20px; background:#000000; }
.c { width:20px; height:20px; background:#888888; }
.b { width:20px; height:20px; background:#ff0000; }
.d { width:20px; height:20px; background:#00ff00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="faq">

  <div class="faqbox">
  <span>Question <div class="a"></div></span>
  </div>

  <div class="answer">
  Answer
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="faq">

  <div class="faqbox">
  <span>Question <div class="c"></div></span>
  </div>

  <div class="answer">
  Answer
  </div>
  
</div>
```